# Find Size or Length of a Youtube Video

Tags: java, youtube, filesize

Im trying to find the size or duration of a youtube video using java. I am using ytapi with ffmpeg in my app to perform actions with a video. This code prints out the size of a url like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html but it gets an error if I try it on the ytapi url.

```
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ytapi.com/?vid=<video-id>&format=direct");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        int size;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            conn.getInputStream();
            size = conn.getContentLength();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
        System.out.println(size);
```

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

If you open the ytapi url in a browser it will start downloading that video. Is there some other way of passing the ytapi url so that I can find the size of the video without downloading it first?